My streamlit app is throwing websocket errors when I direct traffic to its cloud run instance URL
This is my infrastructure for these apps:
GCE Global LB (central GCP project) => Internet NEG => Cloud run app (streamlit app in its own project)
I have seen a lot of stuff online about users having issues running streamlit apps on cloud run related to websockets, but the app runs fine if accessed directly.
The app runs fine in the following cases:

If you access it directly through the cloud run URL ie https://myapp-abc123-uc.a.run.app
If I create a GCE LB in the same project and hook it up to the cloud run app with a serverless backend

My GCE LB is in a central project and I want to route traffic to cloud run apps in other projects. This can be done via internet negs that route to the cloud run app URL (and set a header), this article explains the setup: https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d
That all works traffic routing wise, but the streamlit app throws errors like this when I try to access it via the load balancer: WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.domain.com/my_app/_stcore/stream' failed: .
The LB routing looks like: Path "/my_app" in URL map => backend with request header of "host: myapp-abc123-uc.a.run.app" => internet neg with fqdn of "run.app"
I suspect it might be because, while GCE LBs support websockets ootb, my routing to the URL directly is breaking the connection?
Is there a way I can fix these websocket errors? Do I need to make code changes to support this config or do I need to explicitly pass around headers or something?

I think you can skip the internet NEG if you are in the same shared VPC.

No you can't. I would love to be proven wrong, but cloud run needs a serverless NEG which is not currently supported for the cross project shared vpc LB. Its in the name shared vpc, there's no VPC here my cloud run apps aren't running in private networks and I don't want them to.

Oh, it's the trick with App Engine! (also not in the VPC "because it's serverless), but the option works)

Don't know what you mean by that, but in the UI I was not able to connect an LB to another service projects serverless negs/backend.

Let me detail what I heard, read but never tested. Here the piece of documentation

You must create serverless NEG in the same project as your Cloud Run service.
Then, you can create a backend service, that reference this serverless NEG as long as it is in the same shared VPC


Have you successfully done this because its not possible (please prove me wrong). There is no option to attach to a serverless neg/backend in another project. You have to choose the network to do that and there is no VPC network in play for serverless negs (my cloud run functions don't run in VPCs and want to keep it that way).
